# Tags needing content or listing for improvement

Tags: discussion, tags

- Is there a way of identifying tags that have no content — other than looking through new tags? Or is it likely that these are very few in number anyway?
- Is there a place where one can post suggestions for improvement of tagging information? I was about to edit one tag recently until I noticed that its 'deeper' content has what I would have entered for 'user guidance'. I didn't want to mess up what was there but would have liked to mark the tag for possible improvement.

For instance, the 100th page of tags is https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=100&tab=popular.

Comment: You're talking about the "tag wiki", right? For example, [this thing](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) for the Python tag?

Comment: Thanks for responding, @CodyGray. I've amended my question.

Comment: @CodyGray: To clarify: I realise that tag wikis and tags are closely connected; however, when I asked this question I was interested in tags without contents, not tag wikis.

Comment: Honestly, then, I'm still not clear on what you mean. Tags basically have three different types of "contents" associated with them: there is a long-form wiki, a short wiki excerpt (displayed as a tooltip and other places in the UI), and questions that have that tag. Which of those three contents are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you. Then that means I didn't understand that the things that are displayed as tooltips are excerpts. Somewhere there must be a doc that describes how all this works that I have cleverly avoided.

Comment: Hah, well, I wouldn't be so sure of that! Most of what folks like me know are just things we've picked up over the past 6+ years of being active participants on Meta. Many of them, we campaigned for or against their introduction, argued over how they should best be used, and reported our fair share of bugs. There's a [meta-tag:faq] tag here, with some info, and even more of them over on [the global Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), which used to be one and the same as this site. The excerpts are edited the same way as the full wiki—click the "edit tag info" button to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for the tags that have no wikipostid or excerptpostid.

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/621200) does that:

```sql
select tagname
     , count
from tags
where wikipostid is null
or excerptpostid is null
order by count desc
```

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

If you have a wiki that you want to discuss you can check if there is a chat room that is open for this. For general guidance or advice you might hop into [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). If none of those work for you, posting on meta is fine, provided that you present a proposal how you would like to fix content of a particular wiki. User that answer can then either improve on the proposal or dismiss it.

Comment: I learned about something completely new to me today. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: I realise that tag wikis and tags are closely connected; however, when I asked this question I was interested in tags without contents, not tag wikis. At the same time, I don't care if the question disappears.